# android pattern for login

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to see what you think of how to handle login on Android. I am working on an App right now that requires you to login in order to be useable.  I have two activities so far.  The home screen and the login screen.  I have set it up this way.

The login screen is the main screen.  It asks the user to login.  If the login is successfull it starts the home screen and I call finish in the login activity.  When the user logs out, I finish the homescreen activity and start the login activity.

This isn't working correctly because when I leave the app and then return, even after a successful login, the login screen shows up.

I am thinking, that I will have to keep track of weather the user is logged in or not in a service.  Then the login activity will automatically start the home screen if I am logged in.

Alternatively I can start the homescreen activity that will start the login screen if the user is not logged in.

What's the typical android pattern for this type of scenario?

Comment: This should work just fine. Are you starting the app (for the first time) by launching it from the installer? or from an IDE (like IntelliJ or Eclipse)?

Comment: Also, post your manifest, it may help to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to be more organized you should create something like `MyApplication extends Application` at this class you can create a static method onSessionsCreated and passing a boolean that means show or not your MainScreen(not login screen).

public static void onSessionCreated(Context context, CurrentFan currentFan, boolean startMainScreenActivity) {
     if (startMainScreenActivity) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

If you're using MVC you should create a SessionsController to login the user in your API, after that at the callback login you should call onSessionCreated passing the current user.

```
 if (activity instanceof LoginActivity)
    ((LoginActivity)mActivity).onSessionCreated(user);
```

And then at your LoginActivity you might call:

```
public void onSessionCreated(User currentUser) {
        MyApplication.onSessionCreated(this, currentUser, true);
        finish();
}
```

Using this model you will:
- Use your MVC model
- Use your API to login with your user
- Use the MyApplication class

I think it should be a good approach. Hope be useful for you.